# steps to create https redirects on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services

i have not found an authoritative source on this.

If i have the site www.example.com, what do I need to do to :

1. redirect www.example.com to https://www.example.com
2. redirect example.com to https://www.example.com
3. redirect https://example.com to https://www.example.com

imagine I've setup ec2, and want to use cloud front on aws

Comment: Same domain redirects frlm http to https its easy to do in Cloudfront. Across subdomains use S3 redirects e.g from www to naked domain.

Comment: @Ashan: I haven't seen any easy way to do it when the web server is an EC2 resource. Could you share specifics?

Comment: Based on my understanding you already have a SSL certificate for www.example.com domain which is mapped to EC2? Do you plan to use Cloudfront infront of it for caching or only going to use it for domain redirection?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little tricky because Cloudfront will terminate the https connection for you, forwarding the requests to your web server using http. You probably also want to NOT redirect http://localhost in case you're doing some local checking on the EC2 box and you probably want to set up a health check URL that Cloudfront uses to deterimine the health of your instance that you also don't want to redirect.

We use IIS and used the rewrite module with the following rules. I'm sure the same can be accomplished with Apache, but I'm not fluent in the Apache rewrite syntax. Perhaps someone can add an answer specific to Apache.

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Keep localhost on http"
              stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll"
                  trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}"
             pattern="localhost" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="None" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Ignore health check" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="health.html" />
      <action type="None" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Force Https" stopProcessing="true">
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO}" pattern="https" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```